# How can I detect items without NBT Tags?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a map where it clears normal droppers from your inventory and gives you ones with a tag. But it's detecting the droppers with tags as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear all items from a player's inventory without an NBT tag in 1.15.2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/366987/how-can-i-clear-all-items-from-a-players-inventory-without-an-nbt-tag-in-1-15-2)

Comment: (Flagging an older question as a duplicate of a newer question because this one doesn't actually have an answer that answers the question)

Answer (score -1):

With testfor like...

/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:dropper 1 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:blaze_rod",Slot:1b,Count:1b,Damage:0s}]}

Comment: The question is asking about items in the player's inventory and manipulation via `clear`, not physical blocks in the world (in which `/clear` cannot target).

Comment: then use /testfor

Comment: It's not that simple, nor is `/testfor` generally multiplayer-friendly. `/clear` itself, which is the main issue, cannot specifically remove items without NBT data.

Comment: but with slots, because all your items are inside a slot, and every item has id's and if the item is special then it has NBT tags, and if you want to remove 10 redstone then you make a command where you say,
I want to remove 10 redstone:ID things....

Comment: And that will remove items with NBT data, which is not desired. You can't just tell `/clear` to remove items without NBT data, which is what the question is asking.